# How to access window variable in different .pbl with non-visual object in Powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy, powerbuilder-pfc, powerbuilder.net, powerbuilder-conversion

I have window `w_1` in `P1.pbl`

I have non-visual object `n1` in `p2.pbl`.

In `w_1` having `il_ref`. I would like to access the value to n_1 object.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways to accomplish your task.

You can define an instance variable of type n1 on window w_1.

```
n1 i_n1
```

You would then instantiate the variable via a create statement

```
i_n1 = CREATE n1
```

(unless the object is auto-instantiating)

Methods and variables within i_n1 are now assessable to the window (and vice versa) as long as their scope is designated PUBLIC.

Example of referencing variable on non visual from window method:

```
IF IsValid(i_n1) THEN
  IF i_n1.il_ref > 0... //do whatever
END IF
```

If your non visual is already created as a global, don't make a copy on the window, just change the code above to reference the global.

In general, to have access to classes within a .PBL file, that file must be in the library list of the application.  In more current versions of PowerBuilder this is maintained in the target (.PBT).  There are methods to programmatically change the library list but I won't go into these here.

Comment: Thank you. But Please correct me if'm wrong.

In w_1 havig il_ref=123456 in Á'.pbl.

Now i need to access this value into b.pbl 
In n1(Non-Visual object) 
w_1 iw_w1
iw_w1 = create w_1

int ll_ref = iw_w1.il_ref.
Here iw_w1 not properly set. The value 12345 not showing. Can you pls let me what has to be done?

Comment: Can up update your OP with your example so it is easier to follow?

Comment: In activity.pbl
Window : w_c_detail
Instance varialbe in w_c_detail : ll_sep : 123456 (public long ll_sep)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
In claim.pbl
n_cst_response(newly created object) not added as source control.
ll_sepref(local variable in n_cst_response)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//I would like to access long variable in w_c_detail into n_cst_response.
script:
--------
w_c_detail iw_detail
iw_detail = create w_c_detail
IF IsValid(iw_detail) THEN
ll_sepref = iw_detail.ll_sep 
END IF.

Comment: Question: while debugging the value of ll_Sep in w_c_detail is 12345.But It's not displaying in n_cst_response eventhough it's valid.

Note: iw_detail variable all variables and controls are displaying but all are default values. That means the data not exported into non-visual object properly.

Comment: The default values show because you have created a new instance of the window.  You are not referencing the already opened instance.

Comment: Try: IF IsValid(w_c_detail) THEN ll_sepref = w_c_detail.ll_sep

Comment: without create instance direct we need to write IF IsValid(w_c_detail) THEN ll_sepref = w_c_detail.ll_sep? in n_cst_response?

Comment: so Do we have any other alternative way to sole this problem?

Comment: Re-post with a better explanation of what you are trying to accomplish along with your code.

Comment: Actually i would like to access instance variable from Window to Non-visual User Object. Those objects are existing in different pbls. This is what i have to do.

After that i will try into different ways and let you know.